# Are there any issues for having both Office 2003 and 2007 on one machine?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

My machine has Office 2003 Professional installed.
I am trying to install Office 2007 but there is an option to leave 2003 version.

Has anyone had any issue for having a two different versions of office in one machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally done a side-by-side installation of Office 2007 on top of 2003.
So far there hasn't been any *significant* issues.

**But** there is this one issue that has started getting under my skin.

Whenever I open one version of Word/Excel/PP/etc (say open 2007 versions) and then tries to open 2003 version, I am almost always prompted with this message that initialize office application *for the first time use*.

The process takes about 2~3 minutes and I have started using only 2007 unless I have to use 2003.

But everything else seems to work fine so far.

Answer (score 4):

Been running both in parallel for almost 2 years.  No issues whatsoever.

However, depending on the version of Exchange that's being connected to, there can be problems with having both Exchange 2003 and 2007 and using them both.

Comment: My outlook is connected to Exchange Server 2003.  What kind of problem would occur with Office Outlook 2007? It looks like I can't have two version of Outlook installed...

Comment: > Been running both in parallel for almost 2 years.

On one machine or a whole network? Is it possible to distribute both 2003 & 2007 via a GPO or install script to a whole bunch of PCs?

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with having two versions of Office on the same computer, but they are manageable.

If you use a COM Add-in, then it will be added into all versions; you can't install into one and not another.

When you ShellExecute (e.g. double-click on) a .doc or .docx, then which will it launch?

Are you going to install the Office 2007 Compatibility Pack into 2003?  That can cause problems.

With older versions of Office (not 2003/2007, though) there can also be problems where they used the same .dll files and features "leak" from one version to the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. Specifically with SharePoint (WSS 3.0). If you ever use the 'Edit in Datasheet' functionality of SharePoint lists in Internet Explorer, you can **not** install any Office 2007 components with the SharePoint extensions - they must be explicitly excluded at the time of installation.

No end of headaches!

If you don't use SharePoint, as far as I can tell you should have no problems, aside from some decisions to make re: file type handling (as Richard pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

If you use web sites with Office Web Components (OWC) you'll have issues, but typically these are restricted to intranet sites, and sharepoint (which ajm already mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I had Outlook 2003 installed on one machine, then installed Office Home & Student 2007 (which doesn't include Outlook).  Generally it worked OK, but the insert clip art feature didn't work - it wanted the Office 2003 component for some reason.

It would be better to install one of them in a separate virtual machine to keep things clean.